# How to send custom SITE command when mounting FTP site using curlftpfs

Tags: linux, ftp, iis

I'm sharing a folder from my Windows 10 PC as an FTP site using IIS.  When I mount it on my Ubuntu laptop, I see some folders with unrecognized characters.  If I connect to the site using a regular FTP browser and send the custom command "OPTS UTF8 ON", the folder names are all displayed correctly.  Is there a way to get curlftpfs to send that command every time it connects?  (I'm sharing the folder via FTP so I can access it when I'm away from home.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `utf8` to the list of mount options (e.g. `-o utf8` when mounting via CLI). According to curlftpfs source code, this will add `OPTS UTF8 ON` to the list of commands every time libcurl (re)connects to the server.

There is no method for adding custom on-connect commands in curlftpfs, except for this one thing.